# Intuition behind space-average velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, velocity

Time-average velocity is easy to visualize. But I am struggling with the concept of space-average velocity. I know the formula and definition for these two measures:

Space-average velocity = $ \frac {\int v.ds} {\int ds} $

Time-average velocity = $ \frac {\int v.dt} {\int dt} $

For example, if a particle, starting from rest, is moving in a straight line from point A to point B (a distance of $50 m$) with a constant acceleration of $ 1 m/s^2 $, then the time-average velocity is $5m/s$. I can imagine this as an equivalent of a particle moving with a constant velocity of $5m/s$ in a straight line from A to B in $10s$.

But how do I use and visualize space-average velocity.

Thank you.

Comment: Just plot v(s) via s, and in the same plot the space  average velocity